# Filling NaN based on file name

Tags: python, excel, time-series, dataset, excel-2010

I have a folder, which contains 10 minutes files of everyday. The file name consist just the date and time stamp. For eg. `20211011 00.00.10`. But for some days a few hours data is missing — i.e. few files are missing.

I created a list from  the folder in excel of all the files. I would like Excel to fill in `NaN` for the files missing automatically. How could it be done? I have no idea.

I needed to highlight files based on their sizes also, that I was able to do using conditional formatting, but missing files are little tricky.

I am open to achieving this goal either using python or just Excel. The end goal is to have an Excel sheet where missing files are written as `NaN` and files are highlighted based on size.

Comment: please provide your attempts: a [mre], sample data, your research, what failed; take a [tour] and read [ask] and be more focused (also you can [edit] your question (to add the necessary information))

Comment: For any given day there appears to be an expected set of filenames, so you should be able to iterate through them and detect when one is missing (i.e. you can't open it). You can also explicitly check for their existence using `os.path.exists()` or `Pathlib.Path.exists()`.